# How to position the horizontal and vertical scrollers of scrollview embedding imageview?

Tags: cocoa, scroll

[[self enclosingScrollView]  setHorizontalLineScroll:0];

the above api doesnt works. Help Appreciated...

Comment: Do you want to scroll programatically or do you want to reposition the scrollIndicators?

Comment: want to scroll programatically.

Comment: I want them (Horizontal scroll bar and vertical scroll bar) to be positioned in the center, so that the image in the imageview is located at the center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just fine; you're just trying to use it for something it doesn't do. Read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScrollView/setHorizontalLineScroll:):

> Sets the amount by which the receiver scrolls itself …

The method that sets the scrolling amount does not change where the bars are scrolled to.

How to change where the bars are scrolled to is also covered in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Scrolling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003463-SW2).

Comment: Yeah, The api might be right, but I think, I have use it for something  it doesn't work...might be..